# Random string: does php str_shuffle add entropy

Tags: php, random

I am generating random string with this:

```
 $characters = '0123456789QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm';  
$cl = strlen($characters) -1;
$id = '';
for ($p = 0; $p < $le; $p++) {N
    $id .= $characters[mt_rand(0, $cl)];
}
```

Now, if I do `str_shuffle($id)`will it add entropy i.e. make the string more random?

Answer (score 1):

No. It doesn't.

The str_shuffle just get a random result of your string, so it will give you another random string, but not more entropic.

If you're looking for a more entropic string, you could add special characters to $characters variable or get $le bigger than actually it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want password entropy, might I suggest openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length) or mcrypt_create_iv($length)?

For a custom character set, look up binhex() and convBase() which should be in the PHP manual comments for base_convert()

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware that mt_rand is not the best random number generator, but my question was about applying two consecutive pseudorandom operations. My current assumption is that as long as shuffle does not use mt_rand, it does add (some, possibly very limited) entropy. If it uses the same random number generator, the entropy is not really increased, even though there is different seed. But I'm not an expert on this subject, hence the question.

Comment: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/e797e058c5f9933bdd05349179e6be27e2c0f2a8/ext/standard/string.c#L5339

Uses the C function php_rand() which does not share a seed with mt_rand() but does share a seed with rand(), as far as I know.

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/af6c11c5f060870d052a2b765dc634d9e47d0f18/ext/standard/rand.c#L63

So, potentially, although the entropy gain is likely very small.

Comment: Ugh, I know. I feel sorry for the poor sod who has to audit PHP one day.